# TouchesBegan only called once

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, multi-touch, touchesbegan

I am having an annoying problem. I have a subclassed UIViewController and am checking for touch events with the usual `-(void)touchesBegan` and `-(void)touchesMoved` ... methods. Whatever I try, they are only called for the first touch, the others are completely ignored. I know that this problem has already been solved here:

[Why are UIViewController touchesBegan, touchesMoved & touchesEnded only being called when the first of two touches begins, moves or ends?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122603/why-are-uiviewcontroller-touchesbegan-touchesmoved-touchesended-only-being-ca)

However, the solution there hasn't worked for me. I have set `multipleTouchEnabled` to `YES` on every view, and I set `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` on every subview but the main view on the view controller that I subclassed.

Comment: Why haven't you implemented the `touches` methods on the _view_?

Comment: @matt I already tried that by creating another subclass and everything, the exact same thing happened :(

Comment: Well, I assure you that there is a `touchesBegan` for every finger — a finger _is_ a touch. Can you reduce the problem to a small project and post it? I'll be happy to look at it and tell you what you're doing wrong. There are just too many ways to misconfigure things here.

Comment: Same thing happens. I found out that the other touches are also recorded in event.alltouches, but the methods are still only being called once...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is merely one of understanding how the `touches` events work.

A touch is a finger and a finger is a touch. A touch has a view — the view in which the touch initially happened — and that is its view for the rest of its lifetime. A finger's behavior is sent as a series of touch events to that view.

So now, pretend you have only one view and that the `touches` events are implemented in that view. Then every finger that goes down on the screen *will* call `touchesBegan` *once*. But if Finger 1 was *already* down on the screen when Finger 2 came down, obviously Finger 1 did not begin *now*; that already happened. So *this* call to `touchesBegan` will contain in its `touches` set only Finger 2, because that is the finger that began just now. If Finger 1 is also still down, it will be reported secondarily among the *event's* touches, but this is not *its* touch event so it won't be in the `touches` set.

Comment: It might help you to read my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch18.html

Comment: Thanks, my problem was that the iOS simulator actually called the touchBegan method only once for two simultaneous touches because the started at exactly the same time.

Comment: Yeah, testing multiple fingers on the simulator is a highly artificial exercise because they are artificial fingers. :)

Answer (score 0):

## Description

I think you solved your problem already but I went through this question and did not find the answer even though we had exactly the same issue description.

It was a bit foolish but there's an option that I miss to enable in my storyboard in order to handle multiple touch in my GameScene of type `SKScene`.

When one of the overwritten functions is being called, you should have more than 1 `touch` contained in `touches`.

The way to retrieve the touches is indeed to **browse through them**.

...and those functions are indeed:

- `touchesBegan`
- `touchesMoved`
- `touchesEnded`
- `touchesCancelled`

However, if you are only able to retrieve one touch only, follow the steps bellow:

### Debugging

Here's what you can do to see if you have multiple touches in your set of `touches`:

```swift
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for (i, t) in touches.enumerated() {
            print(i, t.location(in: self))
            self.touchMoved(toPoint: t.location(in: self))    
        }
    }
```

**Output:**
There you should find a `0` for the first touch and a `1` when you touch with 2 fingers... and so on.

### Solution

I case you encounter the same problem than me and have only the touch `t` at index 0 but no other touch, you should see upper in the hierarchy of views if all of them are enabled for multi-touch. In my case it was the view containing the `GameScene` of type `SKScene` that did not have the option `Multiple Touch` enabled. See below:

[image: option to enable multi-touch in the view and its SK instances]

Answer (score -1):

Thank You @matt for the idea. I tried it on an empty project and the methods were still only called once. Then I checked the `touches` array, maybe it was being called once with multiple touches (I was on a simulator). Then I checked `event.allTouches` and voila, there were two touches. Stupid of me to try this on a simulator, but also stupid of apple to call `touchesBegan` once, the `touches` array only containing one element.

Comment: No, there is nothing "stupid" here. You just don't quite grasp how touches work. I've explained in my answer and I've referred you to my full explanation elsewhere. Hope that helps!